# How to recover data from formatted encrypted external hdd?

Tags: macos, password, encryption, data-recovery, hdd

First I formatted an external HDD with Mac OS Extended (Journaled, Encrypted) with password "Psw1".

Then I add some files (*.jpg, *.txt) to it.

Then I reformatted the HDD with Mac OS Extended (Journaled, Encrypted) but with password "Psw23" without wiping.

How can I recover my files if I know my password?

*I've already tried some recovery software (Stellar, EaseUs, etc.), but was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 10):

Unfortunately, it’s gone.

When you encrypt your drive, it gets scrambled with a randomized key so, if you were to look at the actual sectors of the drive, it would just be a jumbled mess.  The key is what takes that “mess” and turns it into usable data.

Recovery programs can’t rescue your data because a) they can’t distinguish between the encryption you did the first time versus the second, and b) being encrypted it can’t “see” the actual file structure to associate what blocks go with what.  This is why and how encryption protects your data from nefarious actors; your data can’t be recovered.

This is also why having a backup is extra critical when you go this route.

Comment: A backup is critical for **any** route. Plus 1 though.

Comment: I should say “extra” critical, @SolarMike because you’re right, it’s critical to begin with.  How many issues, here on AD could be solved if there was a backup!

Comment: @Allan Could we have a tag for "Should've had a Backup", and then we can count them?

Comment: @benwiggy are you trying to break AD?  :)

Comment: Rather cynically, I did post one such on meta a couple of years back, during Hat Season - https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2927/restore-from-backup It's not exactly complete & was just really a bit of a joke… but  it's there ;-)